# Double Elimination, Bye Players Scenario

Tags: node.js, schedule

I want to make double elimination play generator, 
I am facing problem while making loser's bracket in bye players scenario.

like this one:  https://challonge.com/tournaments/bracket_generator?ref=Ur2SStnIFI

how can I manage all these scenarios?

Comment: Show us your code, what you actually tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: I have implemented the scenario in which players are in the count of 2,4,8,16,32,64....
but in all other count of players I have to make bye players for the next round.
so in these cases I am not able to find any logic.